# Show that this function is locally integrable on $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

This is Folland's Introduction to Partial Differential Equations,
Chapter 4 section A Problem 3 a.

> Consider $$G(x,t) = (2\pi it + 4{\pi}^2|x|^2)^{-1},$$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $t \in \mathbb{R}$.
>
> Show that $G$ is locally integrable.

So it suffices to show that this function is integrable over a compact set containing the origin.

However, I'm really skeptical if this is supposed to be true.

Looking at the case where n = 1,
if $G$ is integrable, then by Fubini-Tonelli this function is integrable over a compact set containing $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (with respect to $x$) for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$, but we know that when $t = 0$, $G(x,0)$ is not integrable over a closed ball containing $0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ since we are effectively integrating $\frac{1}{x^2}$ over 0.

What went wrong here?

Thank You

Edit: I forgot the precise statement of fubini tonelli, it just says that for a.e. $t$ $G_t(x)$ is integrable over $\mathbb{R}^n$, not every $t$. However I am still uncertain how one would go about proving this is integrable over $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: No. It needs not be integrable **for any** $t\in\mathbb R$, as you say. If the integral in all variables is finite, then that restriction is integrable **for almost any** $t\in\mathbb R$. One exceptional point makes no difference.

Comment: Yes you are right, so the conclusion I stated is incorrect. Can you offer any insight as to why this function is locally integrable for n=1? (for n greater than 1 it is clear).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case is clear for $n>1$, for $n=1$ simply evaluate the double integral over a closed cube containing 0 to see that it is integrable.